# How to get Pac-Man like constant movement with inputs allowing turns inside lanes and auto turning on collision with a wall, using Raycasts ?

Tags: arrays, unity-game-engine, pacman

I have a grid based level with each grid sized 1x1 unit(default). How do I make my gameobject move through the lanes accelerating in a specific direction (Pacman) until an input is given to change its' direction, or if it collides with a deadend wall and turns to its' right ? The movement needs to be aligned to the middle of the tile. An example of the level with the player object is given below. The green object is the player and red cylinder is a goal, and the scenario in the picture is when no input button was pressed, hereby allowing the player object to auto-turn left.

[Screenshot](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3010784/TT03.png)

Comment: Have you tried anything? I'm guessing not because what you are asking is basic and references could easily be found on google...

Answer (score 0):

@Savlon .
Yes, I did. Currently, I'm only able to move when a key is pressed, which then checks in that particular direction if the tile is walkable or not. And if it is, the move is conducted. This happens only for as long as I've held the key down. The below is the code for the same.

```
public GameObject levelCreator_;
levelCreator temp;
Vector3 playerPos;

int[,] mapArray = new int[13,17];
public bool inhibitPlayerInput;

void Start () {
    DOTween.Init(true, true, LogBehaviour.Verbose).SetCapacity(6000, 6000);

    levelCreator_ = GameObject.Find ("LevelCreatorGameObject");
    temp = levelCreator_.gameObject.GetComponent<levelCreator>();
    mapArray = temp.mapArray;
    for(int i = 1; i<12; i++)
    {
        for(int ii = 1; ii < 16; ii++)
        {
            if( mapArray[i,ii] == 2)     // tile with value 2 is the starting position of the player
            {
                playerPos = new Vector3(i,ii,0);
            }
        }
    }

    transform.position = new Vector3(playerPos.x,playerPos.y,0);
}

void Update () {
    if (inhibitPlayerInput) return;
    getInput();
}

void getInput()
{
    bool inputPressed = false;
    Vector3 newPlayerPos = playerPos;

    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
    {
        inputPressed = true;
        newPlayerPos += new Vector3(-1,0,0);
    } 
    else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
    {
        inputPressed = true;
        newPlayerPos += new Vector3(1,0,0);
    } 
    else if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
    {
        inputPressed = true;
        newPlayerPos += new Vector3(0,-1,0);
    }
    else if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
    {
        inputPressed = true;
        newPlayerPos += new Vector3(0,1,0);
    } 

    if (!inputPressed) return;

    if (mapArray[(int)newPlayerPos.x,(int)newPlayerPos.y] == 1)      // Unwalkable tile check
    {
        return;
    }
    playerPos = newPlayerPos;

    if(mapArray[(int)playerPos.x,(int)playerPos.y] == 0 || mapArray[(int)playerPos.x,(int)playerPos.y] >= 2)
    {
        inhibitPlayerInput = true;
        transform.DOMove(playerPos, TweenWpDuration).OnComplete(() => inhibitPlayerInput = false).SetEase(Ease.Linear);
        return;
    }
}
```